# illegal option: when generating singing certificate

Tags: android, google-developer-tools

Herewith I have attached image of error.

I am trying to generate signing certificate and getting this error.

[image]

Comment: When providing an error on Stack Overflow, please provide it in text (an image is fine _additionally_ if you wish). Text works with search engines better, and it lets readers copy and paste into search engines or IDEs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error states that `\` is an illegal option. I would guess that the issue is the `\` that appears after `-v`.